# Using jquery within a ascx file

Tags: jquery, controls, web, ascx, nivo-slider

I need to create a web user control in Visual Studio that will be embedded into a .NET page within a CMS. The control will be a slideshow using jquery and the popular Nivo slider script. I have imported all the relevant scripts into my VS project.

My questions are: Is it possible to create a web user control using jquery, and where would i put my links to jquery and my code for the slideshow. Is there anyone who could give me a basic outline of how to achieve this

Thanks

R

Answer (score 0):

you should put the slideshow script in user control if you want your control to behave independent of it's consumer and since your control will be put in a CMS then i will recommend using the slideshow scripts in UserControl Itself.

for registering the external javascript/jquery.js references you can use your control's 
`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` method in the page_load event of the control and don't put it in if(!ispostback) block it should be out of it.

You can also use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` for resgistering your slideshow script by putting it into an function say SlideshowFunction(); then you can do like this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ClientScript.RegisterStartUpScript(this,this.Gettype(),"scriptid","slideshowfunction();",true);
    }
```